Unable to build nextjs 14 app router on linux server machine but able to build on my local machine
On the left side is my local machine(mac os catalina) and on the right side is my is my ubuntu server version 23.10.

On server machine:

When i run npm run build this is what the expected output to be:

> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.1

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types  ... ⨯ ESLint: Failed to load config "next/core-web-vitals" to extend from. Referenced from: /Users/tony/workspace/freelance/kurisani/pinnaclefx/.eslintrc.json
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types
 ✓ Collecting page data
 ✓ Generating static pages (18/18)
 ✓ Collecting build traces
 ✓ Finalizing page optimization

Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    2.16 kB         101 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          871 B          87.8 kB
├ ○ /account                             1.88 kB         106 kB
├ ○ /account/accountDetails              2.07 kB         106 kB
├ ○ /account/accountDetails/userDetails  2.38 kB         104 kB
├ ○ /account/deposits                    8.93 kB         106 kB
├ ○ /account/deposits/mastercard         3.02 kB        93.2 kB
├ ○ /account/deposits/successful         157 B          87.1 kB
├ ○ /account/deposits/test               599 B          87.6 kB
├ ○ /account/deposits/visa               2.24 kB        92.4 kB
├ ○ /account/withdraw                    2.53 kB         108 kB
├ ○ /checkEmail                          397 B          87.4 kB
├ ○ /passwordReset                       156 B          87.1 kB
├ ƒ /passwordReset/newpassword/[slug]    157 B          87.1 kB
├ ○ /register                            2.02 kB        98.8 kB
├ ƒ /register/confirmAccount/[slug]      890 B          92.6 kB
└ ○ /signin                              1.1 kB         99.6 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            87 kB
  ├ chunks/23-f78ae0db7f08676a.js        31.3 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-eac071501acc4e50.js  53.6 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)          1.99 kB

However I get the following instead:
> lafinaleftx@0.1.0 build
> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.1
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ⚠ For production Image Optimization with Next.js, the optional 'sharp' package is strongly recommended. Run 'npm i sharp', and Next.js will use it automatically for Image Optimization.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production
root@server:~/workspace/pinnacleftx/frontend# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.

I've also tried npm run build --verbose but not getting any useful information:
> lafinaleftx@0.1.0 build
> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.1
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ⚠ For production Image Optimization with Next.js, the optional 'sharp' package is strongly recommended. Run 'npm i sharp', and Next.js will use it automatically for Image Optimization.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production
root@server:~/workspace/pinnacleftx/frontend# rm -rf .next/
root@server:~/workspace/pinnacleftx/frontend# npm run build --verbose
npm verb cli /root/.nvm/versions/node/v20.12.2/bin/node /root/.nvm/versions/node/v20.12.2/bin/npm
npm info using npm@10.5.0
npm info using node@v20.12.2
npm verb title npm run build
npm verb argv "run" "build" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/root/.npm/_logs/2024-04-16T22_19_47_733Z-
npm verb logfile /root/.npm/_logs/2024-04-16T22_19_47_733Z-debug-0.log

> lafinaleftx@0.1.0 build
> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.1
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ⚠ For production Image Optimization with Next.js, the optional 'sharp' package is strongly recommended. Run 'npm i sharp', and Next.js will use it automatically for Image Optimization.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production
npm verb exit 0
npm info ok

My package.json is as follows:
{
  "name": "lafinaleftx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-icons/all-files": "^4.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "next": "14.2.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
    "sharp": "^0.33.3",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

And I've also tried to delete node_module, .next & package-lock.json files.
I've also tried to increase my ram size from 1gig to 2gig and still getting the same results on my server machine.
I'm using digital ocean by the way.

I found the a solution, so basically i just upgrade my server to 4 gig ram and that seem to fix the build issue.
